# Arbeitsumfeld ist deutschsprachig

Tags: usage

Klingt der Satz, "Mein Arbeitsumfeld ist deutschsprachig" so, als ob das Umfeld selbst Deutsch spricht (will ich nämlich nicht sagen), oder als ob an meinem Arbeitsplatz nur Deutsch gesprochen wird?

Comment: Vielleicht werden die Antworten präziser, wenn du uns nicht nur sagst, was du nicht sagen möchtest, sondern vor allem, was genau du damit ausdrücken willst.

Answer (score 5):

Letzteres, am Arbeitsplatz wird nur (oder primär) Deutsch gesprochen. Den Satz kann man nur absichtlich missverstehen.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree (partially).

> Mein Arbeitsumfeld ist deutschsprachig.

sounds like that the people there are German-speaking as in they grew up in Germany or life there for quite a while and speak it fluently.

So it implicates a bit more than only that your colleagues speak German and **it does not necessarily say that do actually speak German in the office.**

You can say so even if you are in an office where employees are talking English on the phone a lot to order from abroad. One **might assume** from it that among your colleagues the common language is German.

If you want to make sure the sense that German is actively spoken among your colleagues, you might use

> An meinem Arbeitsplatz wird deutsch gesprochen.
>   In meinem Arbeitsumfeld wird deutsch gesprochen.
>   Mit meinen Kollegen spreche ich deutsch.